What are the purpose of these components on my car ECU?
What are these metal "cages" around the capacitors as seen in the circuit below (2x).


We only see the components, not what they are used for and how and why. Best guess is filtering the supply and/or converting supply voltages with switch mode converters.

Rf shields most likely

I don't know for sure, but I suspect they are to deal with vibration which is an issue in the automotive environment. You will note that it is applied to the most massive capacitors only and they have a spring structure built into the sides so they grip the capacitor body.
From here is an alternative approach.

And another one from here:

The metal shroud as opposed to the above plastic mounts would also serve to help cool the capacitor against self-heating, which would tend to extend the useful service life.
